# Updating a field in Child Object from a parent object only while created

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, master-detail

I have a formula field in  Child object which is concatenated with Parent Object field value. Whenever I create a new Child record, the field gets populated correctly. I don't want the child record field to be updated when the parent record field is updated. Use the concatenation as a one time feature. Parent object field is picklist and child object field is formula field. Also using the child object as a related list in parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Formula Field, use a regular text field and update it using a Flow. You can configure the Flow to only run when the record is created.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, formula fields are calculated when the record is queried. The formula field value is by itself, never saved in the database.

There's no formula function on cross-object field references that allows for conditional calculation if the referenced object is new only.

You need to do what @fred says -- don't use a formula field but use a regular Text field that you populate only when the child object is created. This could be done by Flow or apex trigger